# Está dando variável não definida dentro de um if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, else

Art. 42. Podem adotar os maiores de 18 (dezoito) anos, independentemente do estado civil.

> § 1º Não podem adotar os ascendentes e os irmãos do adotando.

> § 2º Para adoção conjunta, é indispensável que os adotantes sejam casados civilmente ou mantenham união estável, comprovada a estabilidade da família.

> § 3º O adotante há de ser, pelo menos, dezesseis anos mais velho do que o adotando.

Art. 45. A adoção depende do consentimento dos pais ou do representante legal do adotando.

> § 1º. O consentimento será dispensado em relação à criança ou adolescente cujos pais sejam desconhecidos ou tenham sido destituídos do poder familiar.

> § 2º. Em se tratando de adotando maior de doze anos de idade, será também necessário o seu consentimento.

Escreva um programa que captura as seguintes informações:

A Idade do Adotante

O adotante é irmão ou ascendente?

É Adoção Conjunta?

Os adotantes são casados ou união estável?

Idade do Adotando

Pais Desconhecidos ou Adotando Destituído do Poder Familiar?

Consentimento dos pais quando não desconhecidos?

Consentimento do adotando (se maior de doze anos de idade)?

A partir das informações fornecidas, o programa deve informar se é possível ou não realizar a adoção!

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
p1 = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))

p2 = int(input("Digite a idade do adotando: "))

p3 = str(input("Você é irmão ou ascendente do adotando? [S/N]: "))

p4 = str(input("É adoção conjunta? [S/N]: "))

p5 = str(input("Os pais do adotando é desconhecido ou ele foi destituído do poder familiar? [S/N]: "))

if p1 < 18:

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

elif p1 - p2 < 16:

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

elif p3 == "S":

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

elif p4 == "S":

  p6 = str(input("Vocês são casados ou possui união estável? [S/N]: "))

elif p6 == "N":

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

elif p5 == "N":

  p7 = str(input("Os pais do adotando conscentiu a adoção? [S/N]: "))

elif p5 == "S" and p2 >= 12:

  p8 = str(input("O adotando conscentiu essa adoção? [S/N]: "))

elif p7 == "N":

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

elif p8 == "N":

  print("Você não pode adotar!!")

else:

  print("PARABÉNS!! VOCÊ PODE ADOTAR.")
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> ````
> Digite a idade do adotando: 12
>
> Você é irmão ou ascendente do adotando? [S/N]: N
>
> É adoção conjunta? [S/N]: N
>
> Os pais do adotando é desconhecido ou ele foi destituído do poder
> familiar? [S/N]: S
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> <ipython-input-3-64423a1d7de4> in <module>()
>
>      12 elif p4 == "S":
>
>      13   p6 = str(input("Vocês são casados ou possui união estável? [S/N]: "))
>
> ---> 14 elif p6 == "N":
>
>      15   print("Você não pode adotar!!")
>
>      16 elif p5 == "N":
>
> NameError: name 'p6' is not defined ```
> ````

Comment: p6 so existe se p4 for igual ```S```

Comment: Importante sempre que postar algo, explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema em vez do exercício todo (inclusive, isso ajuda a localizar o erro) - o excesso de informação é indesejável e atrapalha o foco da postagem. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não analisei o enunciado com atenção então se a lógica do código está errada eu não arrumei. Mexi apenas para executar o que se pretende olhando apenas o código resolvendo o problema relatado.

Eu tirei as chamadas de função `str()` porque não faz sentido converter para `string` o que já é `string`. Não tratei o erro que gerará quando a pessoa digitar algo que não é número onde se espera um número, deixo isso para você, aqui no site tá cheio de exemplo corretos com relação a isso usando `try except`.

Não é tão simples fazer a lógica quando há caminhos diversos para seguir. Não dá para seguir um único bloco `if` porque ele executará apenas um desses caminhos, e no caso existem situações que alguns deles serão executados mesmo que os anteriores também sejam.

Na situação simples de verificação pode fazer um único `if` para definir a não adoção.

Para facilitar a legibilidade do código preferi colocar em uma função e quando a pessoa não consegue adotar ele encerra função. Tem como fazer de outras formas, mas acho essa a mais fácil. Somete mostrará que pode adotar quando não retornar antes, então toda vez que avisar que não pode adotar encerra a função.

O erro se dá porque está tentando verificar o valor de uma variável que não existe, ela só existira se entrasse no `elif` anterior, porém se entrar no anterior não entra mais no que deu erro, o `if` é exclusivo, só entra em um deles. Por isso precisa de `if`s diferentes e controlar o fluxo de alguma outra forma, como mostra no parágrafo anterior.

Quando uma variável só é criada dentro de um `if`, usar essa variável só pode acontecer dentro desse `if`, não pode ser outro `if`, a existência dele é condicional.

Também não consertei o fato de alguns casos digitar qualquer coisa é o mesmo que escolher sim e tem caso que não, isso é inconsistente e só deveria aceitar a letra específica. Também não acertei para aceitar tanto maiúsculo como minúsculo.

Não sei se eu gosto muito da ordem das perguntas. E os nomes das variáveis poderiam ser mais significativos, foi difícil entender o código com nomes mnemônicos que eu desconheço e não são universais.

```
def adocao():
    p1 = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))
    p2 = int(input("Digite a idade do adotando: "))
    p3 = input("Você é irmão ou ascendente do adotando? [S/N]: ")
    p4 = input("É adoção conjunta? [S/N]: ")
    p5 = input("Os pais do adotando é desconhecido ou ele foi destituído do poder familiar? [S/N]: ")
    if p1 < 18 or p1 - p2 < 16 or p3 == "S":
        print("Você não pode adotar!!")
        return
    if p4 == "S":
        p6 = input("Vocês são casados ou possui união estável? [S/N]: ")
        if p6 == "N":
            print("Você não pode adotar!!")
            return
    if p5 == "N":
        p7 = input("Os pais do adotando consentiu a adoção? [S/N]: ")
        if p7 == "N":
            print("Você não pode adotar!!")
            return
    if p5 == "S" and p2 >= 12:
        p8 = input("O adotando consentiu essa adoção? [S/N]: ")
        if p8 == "N":
            print("Você não pode adotar!!")
            return
    print("PARABÉNS!! VOCÊ PODE ADOTAR.")
    
adocao()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TzzgYN). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/gshsdmkl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/AdoptionChoose.py).

Comment: quando o adotando tem doze anos ou mais, ele não pergunta p8

Comment: É o que você colocou no código.